# How to copy function instructions and store them in buffer?

Tags: c, security, control-flow, controlflowguard

Why isn't this code directly storing the assembly instructions of `func` into the buffer? The value of the buffer is junk and doesn't change.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#include <unistd.h> 
char buffer[1000];
uint64_t* addr; 

void func() { 
// here should be what the function really do
    addr = (uint64_t*)&func; 
    memcpy(buffer, &addr, 1000);  // im expecting that the instructions of func will be stored in the buffer 
    strcpy(secret, hash(secret, buffer)); // secret is previous hash of the function before it so i can make  hash chain to verify the control flow integrity  

    // also the 1000 is not the actual size for the function, i just used it here for clarification 
}
```

Comment: `&addr` is the address of the variable `addr`. You want just `addr`.

Comment: I guess by "assembly instructions" you actually mean "machine code".

Comment: In any case, C does not define a way to do what you are trying to do.  Your general approach might happen to work on some implementations, once you correct the `addr` / `&addr` mixup, but there are multiple levels of undefinedness here.

Comment: Even if you assume a Von Neumann architecture with a flat address space and a calling convention that does not use a `gp` register, you still run into problems when the compiler splits the function into multiple pieces and scatters them into different parts of memory. (For example, unlikely code paths like exception handling get moved out of hot pages.) All modern compilers do this.

Answer (score 1):

- There is no guarantee that the `&func` will reference the memory you can read.
- There is no guarantee that `memcpy` will work with this reference on your platform as function pointers **are not** data pointers.
- `uint64_t` is not the type which is guaranteed to hold the reference to the function converted to this type

But if it works, then your code copies the variable address and next bytes which follow it (and it invokes Undefined Behaviour)

```
void func() { 
    memcpy(buffer, (void *)&func, 1000); 
    /* ... */
}
```

This code invoked UB too but it might work on some platforms.